# Integral with Fractions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+\rho} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+a_{i}\rho^{b_{i}}} \mathrm{d} \rho$$

for $a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_i, b_i \geq 0$.

Comment: Did you try for $n=1$ or $n=2$ ?

Comment: try using this. If a function $f$ can be written as a product over it's roots $$f(x)=\prod_{f(w)=0}(x-w),$$ and we are given that $f(z)=0\Rightarrow f'(z)\ne 0$, then we can write $$\frac1{f(x)}=\sum_{f(w)=0}\frac{1}{f'(w)(x-w)}.$$

Comment: I'm sure there is some (absolutely awful) closed form when $b_i\in\Bbb Q_{\ge0}$ but for general $b_i\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ I doubt it. Do you have some reason to expect that there is a closed form?